# Как закрыть от поисковиков контент в фильтре. noindex не предлагать!

Tags: html, seo

noindex закрывает только текстовый контент от индексирования. Нужно же закрыть полностью весь див с фильтром, в котором форма и ссылки. Как это сделать?

Comment: Для закрытия контента от поисковиков есть два способа - самый простой - noindex. Второй способ - смотрите параметры запроса. Чаще всего поле агент содержит слово "robot" и вы можете для поискового робота сгенерировать другой контент (правда последннее время, кажется, за это могут забанить).

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь - контент для поисковиков/ не поисковикво -это основы seo - почитайте таки документацию по sео.

Comment: Может сами почитаете? [Noindex и nofollow: зачем, в каких случаях и как правильно?](https://1ps.ru/blog/dirs/noindex-i-nofollow-kak-pravilno/) @nick_n_a

Comment: noindex и nofollow должны закрыть форму и ссылки тоже. Если не закрывает - расскажите подробнее о проблеме

Comment: @andreymal Цель в том чтоб исключить сразу весь блок, т.к. код формируется компонентом который может подгружать контент с БД, а там уже могут встречаться ссылки. Один из вариантов, уже подсказали, возвращать этот компонент через ajax. Но может есть идеи лучше...

Comment: Только блок, а не страницу целиком? Укажите это явно в тексте вопроса («весь див с фильтром» недостаточно явно, потому что слова «только» тут нет)

Comment: @andreymal Прочел несколько раз свой вопрос. Все изложено достаточно четко: Закрыть весь див, в котором находится фильтр, от индексирования. Слово "только" никакой смысловой нагрузки нести не будет. Причем тут страница, намек на robots.txt?

Comment: Закрытие страницы целиком автоматически закроет весь див от индексирования, используйте robots.txt, ага :)

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно это невозможно сделать. Даже применяя блокирующие директивы в файле роботс, это не гарантирует полное закрытие. Согласно Справки Гугл **[О файлах robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=ru)**:

> *Инструкции robots.txt носят рекомендательный характер. Настройки файла robots.txt являются указаниями, а не прямыми командами.*

Вы можете только сообщить поисковикам, что ваш блок текста не **является важным** следующими способами:

- установить этот текст в спойлер/аккордеон
- применить элементы ХТМЛ5 **[small](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_small.asp)** и/или **[summary](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_summary.asp)**
- применить стили для этого текста
- установить этот текст в "подвале" или что-то подобное

В этом случае поисковики будут понимать, что это не важный текст и понижать его в рейтинге. 
Однако не применяйте стили dispaly:none. Это может быть воспринято как **[Скрытый текст](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=ru)** и может привлечь санкции.